# Where are Adium logs located?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, adium

I have Adium installed on my Mac (10.6.8) but cannot find the chat transcripts stored anywhere. I am able to view them in Adium, but, I do not have a folder

`/Library/Application Support/Adium 2.0`

which is the only place online I can find information about these logs (I do **not** have this folder on my machine).

I am unsure what to search for either (none of the searches I have tried have found anything, but I have not been able to find them either) but really would like to find this file - I know it exists somewhere since Adium is logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `~/Library/Application Support/Adium 2.0`, notice the `~` which denotes your home directory (`/Users/your_username/`), so the whole path should be `/Users/your_username/Library/Application Support/Adium 2.0`.

Comment: Thanks, as a frequent linux user this makes me feel like an idiot for not noticing the `~`.

Comment: Please keep in mind that if you are trying to access this path in your terminal, you should type: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Adium\ 2.0/`